# How to loop while in an IF statement?

Tags: c#, loops, windows-phone-8

I am creating a fitness app that uses this timer specifically: a countdown to prepare yourself(5 sec), then workout countdown(20 sec), and rest countdown(10 sec). The workout and rest countdown is meant to loop 8 before finishing. This is what I have at the minute. I don't know where to place the loop or the condition it needs. Any help?

```
while (rounds > 0 && rounds < 9)
        {
            if (prepTicks > 0)
            {
                txtblPrepare.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                txtblGo.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                txtblTime.Text = prepTicks + " Seconds Remaining";
                prepTicks--;
            }
            else if (workTick > 0)
            {
                txtblPrepare.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                txtblGo.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                txtblTime.Text = workTick + " Seconds Remaining";
                workTick--;
            }
            else if (restTicks > 0)
            {
                txtblGo.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                txtblRest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                txtblTime.Text = restTicks + " Seconds Remaining";
                restTicks--;
            }
            else
            {
                txtblRest.Text = "Congratulations";
                txtblTime.Text = "Times Up";
            }
            rounds++;

        }
        txtblRoundNo.Text = rounds.ToString();
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Be specific...

Comment: Why not simplify it by using 3 seperate timer. One for prepare, one for workout and one for rest?

Answer (score 1):

From what your requirement appears to be, `DispatcherTimer` does the job.

```
//  DispatcherTimer setup
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

In the `dispatcherTimer_Tick` event handler, you can change UI elements' value. The DispatcherTimer runs on the same thread as the UI. Therefore, using the DispatcherTimer instead of the traditional Timer object allows UI updating without the need for the Invoke or BeginInvoke methods. It really is that straightforward. DispatcherTimer gives us a Timer-like object with the traditional Timer’s Tick event, but one that can directly update the UI.

This doesn't block the UI, making your app smoother.